Ensuring consistent common reference among two tables
SQLite schema:
CREATE TABLE Lots (
    Id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY
);

CREATE TABLE Parts (
    Id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY,
    LotId INTEGER NOT NULL REFERENCES Lots
);

CREATE TABLE Inspections (
    Id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY,
    LotId INTEGER NOT NULL REFERENCES Lots,
    PartId INTEGER NULL REFERENCES Parts
);

Each Lot has associated Parts and Inspections, but some of the Inspections are associated with a specific part as well. The problem is that there's nothing ensuring that an Inspection and its referenced Part both reference the same Lot.
I use something like this as a local data store in my app so I'm not worried about these theoretical inconsistencies, but I am interested in learning how to handle this properly.

You can add an additional UNIQUE index in the part table that includes the LotId column:
CREATE UNIQUE INDEX i1 ON Parts(Id, LotId)

And then you can reference this new "super key" in your foreign key constraint:
CREATE TABLE Inspections (
    Id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY,
    LotId INTEGER NOT NULL REFERENCES Lots,
    PartId INTEGER NULL REFERENCES Parts,
    FOREIGN KEY (PartId, LotId) REFERENCES Parts (Id, LotId)
);

Whether you then choose to not include the simple FK on just PartId is up to you.

Ah I think I get the idea, very nice. I assume unique is there just to allow attaching a foreign key to the index, even if it's redundant? In fact, the index could be reversed to Parts(LotId, Id) so it performs double duty for finding parts which reference Lot. But would this work with optional Inspections.PartId, as they are here?

Also: what would I gain by also including the simple FK you mentioned?

Another unexpected side effect: now Inspections needs only one index Inspections(LotId, PartId) for serving both lookups, by either lot or part. :) Before, I needed Inspections(LotId) and Inspections(PartId).

PartId INTEGER NULL REFERENCES Parts is not necessary to specify REFERENCES Parts because you already have the new FK on it.

@relatively_random Yes, unique index or constraint is necessary for an FK. An index is better as you can have INCLUDEs as well. Yes, good idea to reverse the index. Yes it will work with nullable references.
